Bias in linear mixed effects model
I am running a linear mixed model in  lmer of the following form:
Y ~ (1|ID) + Age + Sex + Education + Time*Factor + Time*Diagnosis
My control term is  control <- lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000))
I have about 8800 observations on about 2100 individuals. Variable amounts of missing data.
I use predict_response from the ggeffects package to obtain marginal mean predictions for Time, Factor, Diagnosis. To visualize the model fit, I plotted the actual mean ± standard error from the data against the predicted R with some homebrew ggplot code to graphically assess the model results.
I have about 15 different Y variables. All my models converged easily. But some dependent variables have biased predictions. See figure below:

Any help addressing the issue or model terms is appreciated. I cannot use a random slope because of sampling limitations.

It's difficult to say if there's some lack of model fit, because it's not fully clear how you created the plot (e.g. which options for the predict_response() call you have chosen). It could also be possible that this deviation is expected, because raw mean does not necessarily be close to marginal means that are adjusted for co-variates.
I suggest you evaluate the model fit visually using partial residuals (you can do that with ggeffects: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_partial_residuals.html) or checking model assumptions to see whether a different type of model is more appropriate (you could do this with performance::check_model(), see https://easystats.github.io/performance/articles/check_model.html).
